# Send and Receive 2d pointer array to MPI in c

Tags: c, pointers, parallel-processing, mpi

i wanna send 2d pointer array and each process adds 1 to its element 
here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"
```

function to allocate contiguous memory

```
int **alloc_2d_int(int rows, int cols) {
    int *data = (int *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
    int **array= (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}
```

here is my main there is some logic inside but has nothing with error

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int my_rank;        /* rank of process  */
    int p;          /* number of process    */
    int source;     /* rank of sender   */
    int dest;       /* rank of reciever */
    int tag = 0;        /* tag for messages */
    char message[100];  /* storage for message  */
    MPI_Status status;  /* return status for    */
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    int row1,col1;
    int **mat1;
    int i,j,k,val;
//slaves
    if( my_rank != 0)
    {

       MPI_Recv(&row1,1,MPI_INT,dest,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Recv(&col1,1,MPI_INT,dest,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);


         MPI_Recv(&(mat1[0][0]),row1*col1,MPI_INT,dest,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        for (i=0;i<row1;i++){
            for (j=0;j<col1;j++){
                mat1[i][j]++;
            }
        }
    }

MPI_Send(&(mat1[0][0]),row1*col1,MPI_INT,dest,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

//Master work
else
    {
     //take a matrix from user and it works fine

     for (source=1; source<p; source++)
            {
                    MPI_Send(&row1,1,MPI_INT,source,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&col1,1,MPI_INT,source,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&(mat1[0][0]),row1*col1,MPI_INT,source,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);



            }

 for (source=1; source<p; source++)
            {
                MPI_Recv(&rows,1,MPI_INT,source,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                MPI_Recv(&counter,1,MPI_INT,source,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                MPI_Recv(&(mat1[0][0]),row1*col1,MPI_INT,source,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

                printf("%d   %d\n",counter,rows);

            }

            for(i=0; i<row1; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<col1; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d  ",mat1[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");

            }

        }


    }

    /* shutdown MPI */
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

when i run this code with 4 process it give me that error

 
rank 2 i in job 19 node0_41038 caused collective abort of all ranks
exit status of rank 2 : killed by signal 9

**ANY HINTS**

Comment: I don't see where you allocate memory for `mat1`

Comment: i delete this part of main but i call above function and take input from user

Comment: your program might have been aborted by the oom-killer, you can run `dmesg` to check that. If you need some more help, please post a [MCVE] since the error might be in the code you did not post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run youur program but it is very difficult to get it working because the braces are all over the place and so, not only won't the code compiler, the logic is not entirely clear. However, it appears that the reason for your error is that the non-zero ranks only do a single send, containing a complete matrix, back to rank 0. However, rank 0 issues three receives: for a single int (twice) then for the matrix. The first receive for a single int matches a send for a complete matrix so the program crashes as there is a receive buffer overflow.